How can an application using CuPy be deployed? (VC++ dependency)
I've had no problems using the given documentation to install CuPy and develop with it on my own machine.  But I'm seeing a roadblock in deploying applications using CuPy in a commercial setting to customers on Windows.  It appears that Visual Studio must be installed, not just at development time, but at runtime as well.  And that's not really practical for licensing, or really even just for the mechanics of producing an application package to deploy.
How is this usually handled?  Are there ways to precompile code up front?  Are there known 'runtime' packages with clear licensing terms that include cl.exe?  (Microsoft C++ Runtime Redistributable doesn't seem to have cl.exe as best as I can tell).  I understand with CuPy that precompilation is difficult since the data types aren't even necessarily known up front.
CuPy documentation appears to only have an 'Installation' section at this time.  I cannot find a 'Deployment' section.

Update
The particular line of code causing problems is:
return cp.count_nonzero(fill_ratio >= threshold)
I no longer crash if this is changed to:
return cp.asarray(np.count_nonzero(cp.asnumpy(fill_ratio) >= threshold))
What is special about the count_nonzero function?  The rest of the calculations seem to work just fine without need of a deployed cl.exe

Most functions in CuPy should work without cl.exe. Which functions are you seeing a problem?

He @kmaehashi, the line is: return xp.count_nonzero(fill_ratio >= fill_ratio_threshold) where xp was defined with xp = cp.get_array_module(arr).  This code was written by a third party so I'm not 100% sure about everything in it, but it appears there's code here meant to work with either numpy or cupy.

Is it surprising that count_nonzero would produce a need for cl.exe?  My understanding was that all of this would be JIT compiled?
